# Retrieving value passed through hyperlink in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, hyperlink

My jsp page "view.jsp" has 5 values of cuid which I have turned all 5 into hyperlink. All these hyperlinks are getting redirected to the same page "modify.jsp" having input readonly field cuid. Now to get this readonly field's value, i am passing cuid from view.jsp to modify.jsp through hyperlink paramter "mcuid".

Now, the value is getting passed to the hyperlink fine. I confirmed this from my URL.

But  I am unable to see this value in the cuid field in "modify.jsp". Below is the code I wrote for parameter passing.

1)view.jsp

```
    <td><a href="modify.jsp?mcuid=<%out.print(utils.getCuid().get(i));%>"><%out.print(utils.getCuid().get(i));%></a></td>
```

---

2)modify.jsp

```
<td>Cuid :</td>
<td><input type="text" name="cuid" value="<%request.getParameter("mcuid");%>" readonly /></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am unable to see this value in the cuid field in "modify.jsp".

Because, in `<a>` tag you made mistake, remove `out.print()` where you have assigned value to `mcuid`

```
<a href="modify.jsp?mcuid=<%out.print(utils.getCuid().get(i));%>"><%out.print(utils.getCuid().get(i));%></a>
                                ↑
```

Change to

```
<a href="modify.jsp?mcuid=<%=utils.getCuid().get(i);%>"><%out.print(utils.getCuid().get(i));%></a>  
                              ↑
```

**See also**

- [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

**Update answer to your comment**

To get the value of variable `mcuid` in text box `cuid`

```
<input type="text" name="cuid" value="<%=request.getParameter("mcuid")%>" readonly />
                                        ↑
```

**Now, read what is `<%= %>` in JSP?**

## [JSP Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html)

> A JSP expression is used to insert the value of a scripting language expression, converted into a string, into the data stream returned to the client. When the scripting language is the Java programming language, an expression is transformed into a statement that converts the value of the expression into a String object and inserts it into the implicit out object.

The syntax for an expression is as follows:

```
<%= scripting-language-expression %>
```

> Note that **a semicolon is not allowed within a JSP expression**, even if the same expression has a semicolon when you use it within a scriptlet.

Comment: Oops,Silly mistake :( Thanks a lot for helping me out! :)

Comment: I modified this to code after above suggestion but still not working:(

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aniket. It is perfect now :)